# python-nmap exporting data like -oA in nmap

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a way to output the files in python-nmap like using the -oA option in nmap cli? I can run the nmap scanner no problem, but the output comes out in a dict. i wanted to be able to output all 3 formats automatically

Answer (score 1):

you can use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) for run command and run nmap tools

```py
import subprocess as sub
sub.run(["nmap", "-oA", "/pathFiles/filename with out suffix", "127.0.0.1/32"], shell=True)
```

for pars xml data: ( or see this [pars nmap data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61682356/15523781) )

```py
import nmap
nm = nmap.PortScanner()
nm.analyse_nmap_xml_scan("xmlData")
```

I see this [python-nmap](https://pypi.org/project/python-nmap/) but in code you can't use -oA because in code :

[image]